# How to fill divs with imgs dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flickr

http://jsfiddle.net/84nv2dmL/

I'm trying to get these images of letters to display in order. I tried creating divs dynamically and filling them with the img, but that didn't work. How can I get these letters to display in order?

---

jsfiddle code:

```
function getQueryStringVar(name){
    var qs = window.location.search.slice(1);
    var props = qs.split("&");
    for (var i=0 ; i < props.length;i++){
        var pair = props[i].split("=");
        if(pair[0] === name) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
}

function getLetterImage(tag){

var flickerAPI = "https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";

            return $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
                tags: tag,
                tagmode: "all",
                format: "json"
            })
            .then(function (flickrdata) {
                //console.log(flickrdata);
                var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * flickrdata.items.length);
                var item = flickrdata.items[i];
                var url = item.media.m;
                return url;
                }); 
}



$(document).ready(function() {
        var name = getQueryStringVar("name") || "Derek";

            var str = "letter,";
            var searchtags = new Array()
            for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                //console.log(str.concat(searchtags.charAt(i)));
                searchtags[i] = str.concat(name.charAt(i));
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < name.length; j++){
            var request = getLetterImage(searchtags[j]);
            request.done(function(url) {
                $("body").append("<img src="+ url + "></img>");

                //var ele = document.createElement("div");
                //ele.setAttribute("class", "img" + j--);
                //document.body.appendChild(ele);

                //$("<img src="+ url +"></img>").appendTo("img"+j);

            });
            }
            //$("#img"+i).html("<img src="+ url + "></img>");

});
```

Comment: $("body").append("<img src="+ url + "></img>").append("<br/>");

Comment: Thanks @JAIGANESH but this does not make them display in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to keep track of the order that you are appending your images to the DOM, and make sure that they are in sync with the letters in the name. Created a fiddle with a fix. Comments are in line:

http://jsfiddle.net/84nv2dmL/2/

```
function getQueryStringVar(name) {
    var qs = window.location.search.slice(1);
    var props = qs.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        var pair = props[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] === name) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
}

function getLetterImage(tag) {

    var flickerAPI = "https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";

    return $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {
            tags: tag.char,
            tagmode: "all",
            format: "json"
        })
        .then(function(flickrdata) {
            //console.log(flickrdata);
            var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * flickrdata.items.length);
            var item = flickrdata.items[i];
            var url = item.media.m;
            // return an object with url AND index
            return {
                ind: tag.ind,
                img: url
            };
        });
}



$(document).ready(function() {
    var name = getQueryStringVar("name") || "Derek";
    var urls = new Array(name.length); // array or URLs, in correct order
    var urlCounter = []; // keeps count or URLs received
    var str = "letter,";
    var searchtags = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        searchtags[i] = {
            char: str.concat(name.charAt(i)),
            ind: i
        };
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
        var request = getLetterImage(searchtags[j]);
        request.done(function(url) {
            // when request is done, place image url in 'urls' array, in the correct order
            urls[url.ind] = url.img;

            // push object to the counter array, just to keep count
            urlCounter.push(url);

            // check if all image urls have been collected
            checkComplete();
        });

    }

    function checkComplete() {

        // if the number of URLs received is equal
        // to the number of characters in the name
        // append the images from the ordered array
        if (urlCounter.length == name.length) {
            for (var k = 0; k < urls.length; k++) {
                $("body").append("<img src=" + urls[k] + "></img>");
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div_id").append("<img src="+ url + "></img>");
```

Here `div_id` is the id you gave to the div.
Append adds `img` tag with source `src` to it.

Please give the html code too along with the script to help understand the problem better

Comment: Sure but there's not much in the html anyway. http://jsfiddle.net/8q1tswes/

I tried this, the div tags get created which I can see in the source but are not populated with the img, and nothing shows up.

If I just have $("body").append("<img src="+ url + "></img>"); then all the images show just not in the right order.